# Loop only fires once

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, foreach

Hi guys i am reading a file containing playlists.
(Rows of mp3 file locations)

I currently have the format     ( name ; c:\song.mp3 ; c:\song.mp3 ; c:\song.mp3 ; c:\song.mp3 etc etc)

There are many rows of these in the file.

I have tried both `foreach` loops and for loops to try and solve this (as shown below)

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("playlists.txt");
MessageBox.Show(lines.Count().ToString());

for (int y = 0; y <= lines.Count(); y++)
{
     string[] res = lines[y].Split(';');
     for (int x = 0; x <= res.Count(); x ++)
     {
          if (x == 0) { currentPlaylist = new Playlist(res[x]); }
          else { currentPlaylist.Add(new MP3(res[x])); }
     }
}
```

But for some reason it will only loop once (I have replaced the outer loop with a `foreach` which had the same result.

even if the lines.Count() shown in the messagebox shows a number greater then 1

I'm sure once this is solved it must be basic mistake but Im lost

Thanks

EDIT* this is the file dont know how this will help...

```
Library;C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\Queens of the Stone Age - If I Had A Tail.mp3

playlist1;C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\Red Hot Chili Peppers - Can t Stop.mp3;C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\Red Hot Chili Peppers - Otherside .mp3

playlist2;C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\Red Hot Chili Peppers - Otherside .mp3;C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\Foo Fighters - Best Of You.mp3

playlist3;C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\Red Hot Chili Peppers - Otherside.mp3;C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\Foo Fighters - The Pretender.mp3

playlist4;C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\Foo Fighters - Everlong.mp3;C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\Foo Fighters - My Hero.mp3;C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\I Am Giant - City Limits.mp3
```

I put it in as code so it would be easier to read

The only issue i am having is that the inner loop only fires once and i am unsure as to why.

Something in the following ....

```
for (int x = 0; x <= res.Count(); x ++)
     {
          if (x == 0) { currentPlaylist = new Playlist(res[x]); }
          else { currentPlaylist.Add(new MP3(res[x])); }
     }
```

is causing the outer loop to only fire once no matter the amount of lines in the code, if i remove the inner loop the outer loop loops the expected amount of times

Comment: What would be your expected result? You overwrite `currentPlayList` every time `x` becomes 0 (once every time `y` increases), so `currentPlaylist` will only ever contain MP3's from the last line.

Comment: Where are you declaring the variable currentPlaylist? Also why can't you use lines.Length instead of lines.Count()? Same goes for res.Count() also.

Comment: My file has 5 or so rows, hence i would expect this to create 5 or so playlists.

Comment: each row will have a number of songs, after the name hence i use lines.count to check whether the file has multiple playlists, and res.count to loop through the songs in the row ?

Comment: currentPlaylist is a global variable

Comment: Please show the content of your file

Comment: Show PlayList and MP3 classes (at least the constructors)

Comment: playlist is just a string "name" name of the playlist  (taken on construction) and mp3 is just a file containing string "filelocation" the location of the file(on construction) its nothing fancy or worth posting

Comment: *playlist has an observable collection of mp3 forgot to add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question and comments you wrote, I think you are looking for something like:

```
// This method read the file and populate a List of Playlist.
// Each PlayList contain a list of MP3 songs
public List<Playlist> GetPlayLists()
{
    // read all lines from the text file
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\Temp\playlists.txt");

    // declare a playlists variable to hold all the playlists and their songs
    var playlists = new List<Playlist>();

    // Loop through all the playlists (each line in the text file represents a playlist)
    for (int plIdx = 0; plIdx < lines.Length; plIdx++)
    {
        // split in order to fins all the MP3 songs
        string[] res = lines[plIdx].Split(';');

        // create a new playlist (its name is passed into the constructor)
        var playlist = new Playlist(res[0]);

        // loop the songs (starting from index 1 since index=0 is the playlist name)
        for (int songIdx = 1; songIdx < res.Length; songIdx++)
        {
            // Add to the playlist each song
            playlist.Add(new MP3(res[songIdx]));
        }
        playlists.Add(playlist);
    }

    return playlists;
}

// Play list class containing all the MP3 songs (each line in text file)
class Playlist
{
    public List<MP3> SongList { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Playlist(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        SongList = new List<MP3>();
    }

    public void Add(MP3 mp3)
    {
        SongList.Add(mp3);
    }
}

// MP3 Song class
class MP3
{
    public string Location { get; private set; }
    public MP3(string location)
    {
        Location = location;
    }
}
```

This is how your playlists variable looks like after it has been populated with your playlists.txt file:

[image]

Do the following steps in order to make it work. Once working, you will have a reference so you can simply merge it into your existing project.

**Create a new Console Application**
Your class program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // FileReader is the class that contains the method that read from the playlists.txt file
        var filereader = new FileReader();
        var playlists = filereader.GetPlayLists();
    }        
}
```

**Create a FileReader class and put the GetPlayLists method into**

```
class FileReader
{
    // This method read the file and populate a List of Playlist.
    // Each PlayList contain a list of MP3 songs
    public List<Playlist> GetPlayLists()
    {
        // .....
    }           
}
```

**Put the other classes PlayList and MP3.**

Now you should be able to run it without any issues.

Comment: sadly this didnt even read the first line... im extremely confused now as to what the error is and why it was only looping once

Comment: I fix an issue in the code. I ran it with the file you post and it works fine. Please try again (Note, the file need to be in c:\temp\playlists.txt

Comment: It does not work, nothing happens not even the first line, the file is within the project so using File.ReadAllLines("Playlists.txt"); should work. my code worked for the first line, i am wondering how to edit it to work for the rest thats all i ask.

Comment: I will try and help you. Give me few minutes and I will update my answer so you can check it. You will have to create a new project so you can see it works fine. Once it will work, you will be able to merge it with your existing project.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should throw an exception, as far as I can see. You use <= in your loop conditions, but when `x == res.Count()` you can not access `res[x]`, because the index must be between 0 and Count-1.

Try to replace `<=` by `<`, at least.

And don't use `Count()` on arrays. They have `.Length` property.

Comment: i replaced all <= with < and also count() with .Length and the result remains the same, Library is read fine but the others wont read.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you posted is the file you're reading then each line contains a single file location of the mp3. After splitting each line with ';' you can safely assume that the 2nd entry of the new array is the file path.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("playlists.txt"); // 100 lines 

for (int y = 0; y < lines.Length; y++) loops through array index 0 to 99
{
     string[] res = lines[y].Split(';'); // lines[y] should be something like c:\song.mp3 ; c:\song.mp3 ; c:\song.mp3
     // res[0] = Library
     // res[1] = C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\Queens of the Stone Age - If I Had A Tail.mp3
     currentPlaylist = new Playlist(res[0].Trim());
     currentPlaylist.Add(new MP3(res[1].Trim()));
}
```

Or if each line has multiple file paths..

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("playlists.txt"); // 100 lines 

for (int y = 0; y < lines.Length; y++) loops through array index 0 to 99
{
     string[] res = lines[y].Split(';'); // lines[y] should be something like c:\song.mp3 ; c:\song.mp3 ; c:\song.mp3
     // res[0] = Library
     // res[1] = C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\Iphone Music\Queens of the Stone Age - If I Had A Tail.mp3
     currentPlaylist = new Playlist(res[0].Trim()); // res[0] is the playlist name right?
     for(int x = 1; x < res.Length; x++)
     {
         currentPlaylist.Add(new MP3(res[x].Trim()));
     }         
}
```

Comment: my issue is, i can read the library line perfectly with the above code, however the loop will only fire once (for the first line of the file) and then i lose the rest of the information.... there will be many more then one mp3 per line

Comment: i know the error is within the centre loop as i just removed the code from within it and it looped 5 times like i want it to.

Comment: i replaced my code with yours to test, but i had the same result, i tried adding a messagebox.show("true"); after your for loop, and it did not even fire once....

Comment: Instead of a message box use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine before currentPlaylist.Add

Comment: i normally do, this way is just more visible for me when i'm trying to figure things out

Comment: @AMerz are you familiar with breakpoints? If so then use it to debug your code line-by-line. As all of us here see that our suggestions SHOULD work but unfortunately not in your case as we cannot see the actual data flowing through your application. This might be a threading issue but it's hard to believe that it is.

Comment: I have already narrowed it down to be something wrong with the inner loop as i have said.. something in the following is causing the outer loop to only fire once no matter the number of lines in the file is..                       for (int x = 0; x <= res.Count(); x ++)
     {
          if (x == 0) { currentPlaylist = new Playlist(res[x]); }
          else { currentPlaylist.Add(new MP3(res[x])); }
     }

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should not initialise currentPlayList in the inner loop as it will get reinitialised every time it loops through y

```
Playlist currentPlaylist;
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("playlists.txt");

for (int y = 0; y < lines.Length; y++)
{
    if (y == 0) { 
       currentPlaylist = new Playlist(); 
    }

    string[] res = lines[y].Split(';');
    for (int x = 0; x < res.Length; x ++)
    {
        currentPlaylist.Add(new MP3(res[x])); 
    }
}
```

Your outer loop actually runs more than once, but because you reinitialise the playlist, the only state that is persisted at the end of the outer loop is the very last iteration, this giving the appearance of having run only once.